# Как обратиться к переменной, находящейся внутри класса

Tags: python

```
from datetime import datetime
import backtrader as bt

class someClass(bt.Strategy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.close = self.datas[0].close  # все значения одной колонки

# Пробуем вытащить self.close и поместить в список, но получаем адрес ячейки 
# функции`[[<function Strategy.close at 0x0000007761290550>], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`
# `func_inlist()` в примере возвращает одно значение. А если значений много и они состоят из  разноразмерных списков - как организовать модуль?

def func_inlist():
    closeC = [someClass.close]
    # closeC = list(someClass.close) - неитерабельный вариант т.к. closeC остается функцией
    return closeC

hello = func_inlist()

def func2():
    cond1 = hello
    cond2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    pre_X = [cond1, cond2]
    return pre_X
DEMON = func2()
print(DEMON)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
    data = bt.feeds.GenericCSVData(
        dataname='sbrf_fish.txt',
        separator='\t',
        dtformat='%d%m%y',
        openinterest=-1,
        fromdate=datetime(2019, 1, 1),
        todate=datetime(2021, 1, 1))
    cerebro.adddata(data)
    cerebro.run()
```

Вытащить переменную без связки с Backtrader (в тестовом режиме и переменными в виде вручную заданных списков) одним из возможных методов по следующему примеру получается:

```
# 1
f = someClass(object)
f.var1 = [1,2,3]
f.var2 = 'asdf'
someClass(f)
```

```
# 2
XClass = someClass()
XClass.close
```

Через **kwargs тоже вытаскивается, но этот вариант даже не рассматриваю, т.к. списков очень много.
Получить доступ к self.close находясь внутри класса возможно. Но принципиально нужно вытащить close как в представленном коде.
Что я не так делаю?

Comment: "нужно вытащить close как в представленном коде." - что это означает на нормальном человеческом языке?

Answer (score 0):

- Называйте классы с большой буквы, а переменные, в том числе экземпляры классов с маленькой буквы, чтобы не было путаницы
- `someClass.close` - это переменная класса, а `self.close` - это переменная экземпляра класса, это не одно и то же. Для начала разберитесь, где у вас что и что вы вообще хотите. Пока это не очень понятно. Оба варианта - и переменная класса и переменная экземпляра - всегда видны снаружи, с этим нет никаких проблем. Просто вам нужно понять, где у вас что и в чём между ними разница. Переменная класса - одинаковая на весь класс, а переменная экземпляра у каждого экземпляра класса своя, отдельная.

```
obj = someClass()
print(someClass.close) # переменная класса
print(obj.close) # переменная экземпляра класса
```

Comment: Переменные класса и переменные экземпляра класса выводятся без проблем, если не запускать backtrader, как я указал в вариантах, через которые и пробовал. Это не значит, что в рабочем коде я так и делал. Проблема видимости переменных возникает при запуске движка bt.

Comment: @Abudallil Ну тут вопрос - что такое этот backtrader и как он работает. Если он запускает отдельный процесс, то туда копируются данные и всё сложно.